How can I add ".html" to the end of a URL in Next.js for CloudFront with S3?
I want to add ".html" extension to the end of a URL in Next.js because S3 origins with CloudFront hosting without CloudFront functions doesn't work without fullpath except root directory.
How can I add ".html" to the end of a URL in Next.js?
I tried "trailingSlash" option with false, but it doesn't work because ".html" extension is not added.

What if you try naming your file .html.js?

1. Update next.config.js with Rewrites
In your next.config.js, you can add a custom rewrite rule that appends .html to the paths.
app/
   profile.html/
      page.tsx

// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',       // Match all paths
        destination: '/:path*.html',  // Append ".html" to all paths
      },
    ];
  },
};


2.  Middleware Option
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  // If the URL doesn't have an extension and it's not the root URL
  if (!pathname.endsWith('.html') && pathname !== '/') {
    // Rewrite the URL to add '.html'
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
    url.pathname = `${pathname}.html`;
    return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
  }

  // Continue the request if it already ends with '.html'
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|favicon.ico).*)'], // Apply to all pages except API, _next, and favicon
};


